How to enroll a peer/orderer/admin type identity using Fabric CA when LDAP is enabled?
I have setup a fabric network using docker. This is not the default testnetwork provided by fabric.
In this setup I am using 3 CA,  2 for orgs and 1 for ordererOrg.
Previously when I was registering and enrolling users things worked fine. But when I enabled ldap in fabric-ca-server-config.yaml and skip the :                      fabric-ca-client register --id.type peer...
command the enrolled users get a default OU=client in X.509 from fabric CA. As a result I am unable to join peers to a channel.
How to solve this?
I tried to add OU=peer in LDAP. But if I do that I get OU=client,OU=peer in the resulting peer's signcert. When I try to start the peer it throws error that the OU has OU=client+OU=peer
